Space colonization novel with "grey matter"
What I think I remember is there is something called grey matter, it’s used to create objects but you have to say the name of the object to create it and you have to go back every once and a while to name it again.
I remember something about a colony (maybe the 13th colony?) and it falls into like a crack or hole in the planet.
I think I remember the main character had a roommate that become a love interest and they also lived with an old lady. Maybe she worked in a greenhouse?

(There's a grey goo that turns out to create objects in Robert Sheckley's I See A Man Sitting On A Chair, And The Chair Is Biting His Leg — but that doesn't match any of the other points.)
